# Associations not working in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
  <ol class="noDots">
   <% # @screening.cinema.each do |screening| %>
    <li> 
     <h3><%= screening.cinema.name %></h3>
    </li>
   <% #end %>
  </ol>
```

Hi everyone,
There is an association between cinema and film through screening. Film model is separate and cinema is separate. Screening combines them together. In the cinema model, everything seems to work properly <%= screening.film.title %> works perfectly and displaying them in a loop works.

I want to create a dropdown of cinema.name with the link and it takes you there. The association has to exists as some movies in different cinemas.

Is that possible as the code above doesnt work for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In terminal run Rails c, then get screening as in your controller, 'screening = Screening.find_by_id(some_id)' and then run 'y screening.cinema' to see if it returns one result or an array. You might need to do 'screening.cinema.first.name'

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2245081 @BookOfGreg

Comment: What happens with 'screening.cinema.name' or 'screening.cinema.first.name'?

Comment: undefined method `cinema' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That is quite odd given that screening.cinema returns a record with a .name field and even if it is an array the .first should have stripped it out. Probably won't work at this stage, but you could try s = screening.cinema then s.name but its a long shot given the rest didn't work.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2245322

Comment: Well that is how you get one extracted. Can you now try it with more than one Cinema in the screening? The results should be similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are getting a lot "nil object" errors. Double check your controller to see what variables you are defining there that can be accessed in the views.

Eg, if you are setting @film, then you can traverse the associations with something like:

```
<% @film.screenings.each do |screening| %>
  <li> 
    <h3><%= screening.cinema.name %></h3>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

You should be able to alphabetize by cinema name as well, if you eager-load them when you grab the list of screenings:

```
<% @film.screenings.includes(:cinema).order("cinema.name ASC").each do |screening| %>
  <li> 
    <h3><%= screening.cinema.name %></h3>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
<h3><%= screening.cinema.name %></h3>
```

This line should read...

```
<h3><%= screening.name %></h3>
```

And you could have this dropdown box in a form with a Submit button next to it to take you to that page...

Comment: to not confuse yourself u may want to change |screening| to |cinema|

Comment: Hi @Norto23 i tried the method but i am getting the following error: undefined method `cinema' for nil:NilClass on line 48. 48: <%  @screening.cinema.each do |cinema| %>.

Comment: @atbyrd, i also tried your method but nothing, the whole code looks like this... https://gist.github.com/2245104

Comment: Ok so if I'm correct in saying that Cinema's has_many Screenings, then the line should read cinema.screening.each do |cinema| . Maybe make sure your associations are correct

Comment: It might help to post your models for Cinema, Screening and Film

Comment: @Norto23 undefined method `screening' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Line 5 in that gist should be cinema.name, not screening.name

Comment: @BookOfGreg I tried that, undefined method `cinema' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I think you need to look at your models and how they interact first. Looks like you've got some weird associations going on

Answer (score 2):

From what I see screen has_many :cinemas( not cinema has_many :screenings)
so

```
   <%  @screening.cinema.each do |cinema| %>
      <li> 
        <h3><%= cinema.name %></h3>
      </li>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `cinema' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This is the correct answer. You need to assign @screening to the proper screening in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

please show the screening model and the cinema mode, but based on the gist..

Assuming

```
class Screening     
   belongs_to :film 
   belongs_to :cinema. 
   .....
 end 

 class Film
      has_many :screenings
       has_many :cinemas, :through => :screenings 
 end

 class Cinema
    has_many :screenings,
     has_many :films, :through => screenings 
 end
```

I think what you want is something along the lines of the following.

```
 <ol class="noDots">
   <% # @screenings.each do |screening| %>
    <li> 
      <h3><%= screening.cinema.name %></h3>
    </li>
   <% #end %>
 </ol>
```

Assuming that you set @screenings to subset of screenings you want in the controller..

Comment: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

Comment: without the controller code, and the model code  we are all just guessing..  So you have the film, and you want a list of all cinemas that are screening that film?  or a a list of all the screenings>..  You would do something like @film.screenings.each do |screening|  assuming you had has_many screenings in your film model.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as it worked on your single screening in the comments.

### In the controller

```
@screening = Screening.find(some_id)
```

### In the view

```
<% @screening.cinema.each do |s| %>
  <li> 
    <h3><%= s.cinema.name %></h3>
  </li>
<% end %>
```